# Retain beginning of linked list when adding

Tags: c

I want to retain the beginning of the linked list in the code below. I don't think my code has any problems, but when I add two nodes and call `print` it will show me the first name of the second node.

EDIT: IT SHOWS NOTHING NOW! IT IS EMPTY

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node {
char Number[10];
char FirstName[10];
char LastName[10];
char FatherName[10]; 
char Email[20];
char SiteName[30];
struct node *next;
};
void print( struct node* list)
{
    printf("print1");
        printf(list->FirstName);
        printf("print2");
}
void addNode(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *current = head;
puts("*******Now you can insert a new person****");
    struct  node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            printf("FIRSTNAME: ");     
        gets(newNode->FirstName);
        printf("LASTNAME: ");      
        gets(newNode->LastName);
           printf("FATHERNAME: ");    
        gets(newNode->FatherName);
           printf("EMAIL: ");      
        gets(newNode->Email);
           printf("SITENAME: ");   
          gets(newNode->SiteName);
      //create new node

     newNode->next = 0;  // Change 1
        //check for first insertion
        if(current->next == 0){
       current->next = newNode;
       printf("added at beginning\n");
    }
    else
    {
        //else loop through the list and find the last
        //node, insert next to it
  while (current->next != 0) {
    current = current->next;
  }
  current->next = newNode;
  printf("added later\n");
    }
    }
//*************************************************************************
int main()
{
    /* This won't change, or we would lose the list in memory */
    struct node *root;   

    /* This will point to each node as it traverses the list */
    struct node *conductor;  
    root = malloc( sizeof(struct node) );  
    root->next = 0;   
       addNode(root);
    addNode(root);
    conductor = root; 
    //*********************************
    print(root);
    if ( conductor != 0 ) {
        while ( conductor->next != 0)
        {
            conductor = conductor->next;
        }
                        }
    /* Creates a node at the end of the list */
    conductor->next = malloc( sizeof(struct node) );  
    conductor = conductor->next; 
    if ( conductor == 0 )
    {
        printf( "Out of memory" );
        return 0;
    }
    /* initialize the new memory */
conductor = root;
if ( conductor != 0 ) {
 /* Makes sure there is a place to start */
    while ( conductor->next != 0 ) {
      puts( conductor->FirstName );
puts( conductor->LastName );
        conductor = conductor->next;
    }
    puts( conductor->FirstName );
}
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gets(current->FirstName);
```

`current` points to the same `struct node` as `head`, the head node being passed to `addNode`. Therefore you'll be overwriting the values of the `struct node` passed to `addNode` and not the new node being created with the above code.

I'm assuming you should be storing the first name, last name, etc, in the node pointed to by `newNode` and **not** `current`.

You're code is also susceptible to buffer overflows by using `gets`; consider using `fgets`. I also hope `FirstName`, `LastName`, etc, are defined as `char[]`s and not `char*`, so they have memory allocated for them in order to store the strings.

Comment: Thanks,yes they defined as char [] ,i dunno fgets what should i do exactly?

Comment: @nikparsa: `fgets(newNode->FirstName, sizeof(newNode->FirstName), stdin);`, so that no more `char`s than the size of the array are read into the buffer. Since `newNode->FirstName` is an array and not a pointer, you can use `sizeof` to get the size of the array.

Comment: it shows me nothing I changed the code from  gets(current->FirstName);
 to the thing that you told me and also i malloc the newnode firstly

Comment: @nikparsa: We can't really tell what else is wrong with your code without seeing the full code.

Comment: @nikparsa: The `addNode` method is working fine now. You just have a whole bunch of unnecessary junk in `main`, and you're trying to print `root` which has uninitialized strings. [Here's an example](http://ideone.com/eZdlq) with some of your junk chopped out to show you. I also don't know how you got your indentation so bad.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Your print function now outputs nothing because the root node is empty. This is what your list looks like:

```
+------+        +------------------+       +-------------------+
| root |  --->  | first user entry | --->  | second user entry |
+------+        +------------------+       +-------------------+
```

So, if you replace

```
print(root);
```

with

```
print(root->next);
```

it will print the first entry made by the user.

---

**OLD ANSWER**: In this line:

```
gets(current->FirstName);
```

you overwrite the value of `current->FirstName` with the new value. Since `current` points to `head`, you overwrite the value of the first node.

To fix this, *first* `malloc` the new node and *then* `gets` the values into it (into `newNode`, not into `current`). Don't forget to allocate enough space to `newNode->FirstName` and the other fields, or `gets` will overflow your buffer. In fact, [please don't use gets at all](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1049157810&id=1043284351).

Comment: Thank you ok,I will change gets but how should i use malloc I have it for new Node I couldn't understand your mean

Comment: @nikparsa: It depends. In your struct, are `FirstName` etc. `char*`s or `char[...]`s? If they are `char[...]`s, you can disregard my comment about allocating space for them.

Comment: @nikparsa: Ah, ok, then it's fine.

Comment: well,now what should i exactly do?

Comment: @nikparsa: We won't write your code for you. ;-) Do you understand now why your code does not work? Do you understand (conceptually) what you need to do to fix it? If not, what exactly is unclear?

Comment: no I don't know! I am dummiest coder in this world i'm totally confued what you have wrote I have malloc now why you tell me again this

Comment: you mean i should use newnode firstly and then malloc it and gets should be with newnode? this is your aim?

Comment: @nikparsa: Yes, exactly! Create and malloc newNode, then `gets` (or `fgets`) the values **into newNode, not into current**, and then add the node to the list.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6127/discussion-between-heinzi-and-nik-parsa)

Comment: sorry I wasn't here it was 1:30 AM I went to bed